# How to set autoReconnect after configuration error in Play Framework?

Tags: sql-server, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have an application on Play Framework 2.3, and connecting to SQL Server (2008, 2012 and 2014 versions). Configuration looks like this:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.101;databaseName=myDatabase;SelectMethod=direct;autoReconnect=true"
```

That works propperly except for application starting before starting SQL Server. In that case play generates an error:

```
Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

Is, that possible, to set PlayFramework automaticly reconnect, after that error, when Play arrives a new request, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HikariCP has [a property to do exactly what you want](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#infrequently-used):

> **`initializationFailFast`**: This property controls whether the pool will "fail fast" if the pool cannot be seeded with initial connections successfully. **If you want your application to start even when the database is down/unavailable, set this property to false**. Default: `true`

You can use [play-hikaricp module](https://edulify.github.io/play-hikaricp.edulify.com/) to replace the default pool (BoneCP) and then configure HikariCP as explained above.